# Python can't find my static folder "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1653

Tags: django-staticfiles

Okay so I've tried almost everything; staticfiles dir, static root, collect staticfiles. I don't know where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing. Please help guys, I've been going over this for the past 3 days.

My HTML

```
{% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1", shrink-to-fit="no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ScP.png)

Answer (score 6):

```
"STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]"
```

On this variable, just write 'S' after DIR it might solve your problem, like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rerun the server again!
Tap `ctr` c to stop the server.
Then type this in the terminal to run the server again: python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are not serving the static files correctly, the same happens if you want to run the admin page. I'm dealing with the same and trying to solve this from the official page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

regards!

Comment: I put the "DEBUG = True" and an image was served correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you load your static directory?
try  this

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did. I even tried {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: what is the structure of your static directory? i assume that you have `static -> css - > style.css`  in this case you have to import like this `href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"`

Comment: It's directly under the static folder.
```
static -> style.css

Hence,

href="{% static 'style.css' %}

```
Though it was once in a css folder, but I'm trying everything in my power to get this solved

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py remove the STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') and instead leave just the STATICFILES_DIRS.
Something like this...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```